# How do I upgrade packages used by iPython?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am using iPython on OSX (on system, not inside a virtualenv) and importing pandas into a notebook. My system python is Python 2.

The version of pandas visible in the notebook is 0.16.2:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__
```

I want to use pandas 0.18. So I have quit the notebook and run:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

This appeared to install ipython 4.1.2 and pandas 0.18.0, but if I run:

```
ipython --version
```

I see v4.0. And running my notebook still shows pandas 0.16.2.

How do I upgrade my packages so that I can use pandas 0.18 inside my notebook?

Comment: Try opening a new notebook and import pandas again.

Answer (score 2):

The `ipython` command invokes the respective python script, which is typically stored at `/usr/local/bin/ipython`. The first line of this script denotes the python version to be used. In my case it is `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` which means that ipython is using version 3.6 of python. Use the command `which ipython | xargs head -n 1` to read this first line of your ipython script.
Once you know which python version ipython is using you can invoke the upgrade command. In my case, I have to execute  `pip3.6 install --upgrade ipython` and `pip3.6 install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: Hie @jboockmann, It works for me as well...but with small correction.. Instead of 'pip3.6 install' , i had to give only 'pip install'

Answer (score 1):

Using the following command you can update ipython,
Open cmd and type the command:

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip` most likely points to `python3`, you can sepecify what pip to use specifically:

```
pip2 install -U ipython
pip2 install -U pandas
```

Another reason can be having more than one version of python2 installed so pip may well point to another that interpreter, adding `which -a pip` and `which -a python` will show you what is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the iPython / Jupyter notebook, Padraic's second thought is probably correct, you're probably running the python that came with Anaconda, try `conda install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

[image: ipython3]

To change ipython from version 3.8 to 3.10, I edited first line of /usr/bin/ipython3 to `#!/usr/bin/python3.10`